# Idea and command line java produce different date with same timezones

Tags: java

I run a part of code in Idea 2019.3.1 and with CMD

```
javac Main.java
java Main
```

CMD Output:
**23/May/19 06:19 AM**

Idea Output: **23/May/19 07:19 AM**

Why I get different responses?

**Java version**:  "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String timestamp="2019-05-23T06:19:00.000+0000";
        ZoneId timeZone=ZoneId.of("Africa/Casablanca");
        ZonedDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(timestamp, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH))
            .atZoneSameInstant(timeZone);
        String formatedParsedData = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yy hh:mm a").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH).format(dateTime);
        System.out.println(formatedParsedData);
    }
}
```

Comment: First guess is that with Locale English one of those is accounting for British Summer Time and one isn't - BST is 1 hour ahead in May. I'd guess IntelliJ has different Locale configuration, though not sure where that sits in the JRE

Comment: Check if it is English locale issue by passing in a date in December and see if they are the same - that would confirm or rule out that line of thought

Comment: What does `getZone()` return for the `DateTimeFormatter` in both cases?

Comment: @Chris i set December,  they are the same

Comment: Cool, so it probably does relate to BST. There's lots of info including daylight saving support here - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/troubleshoot/time-zone-settings-jre.htm#JSTGD374 I guess the intelliJ JRE and your installed JRE are getting their locale data from different ppaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible because IDEA and your cmd are getting your locale data from different places, or even the JRE is not even the same one if you have more than one installed.

Also Morocco has been going on and off summer time saving a lot recently, so this might be an issue as well.

Comment: For me exactly that was the case: JRE is not even the same one if you have more than one installed